# Deducting another room that isn't fully for business use

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction

I work from home and have a bedroom that I want to deduct for business use. I already have a room that I'm deducting. The bedroom will have personal use about 7 days per year. Can I simply pay the business back for those days to avoid breaking the exclusivity rule?